# Trying to populate a singly linked list

Tags: java, list, structure

So I have a singly linked list in java

```
 public class ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode next;

      ListNode(int x){ 
         val = x; 
      }
  }
```

Now what I am trying to do, is populate the list with the `String number = "213214"` which is essentially just a  number. Now each node will be  a single digit from that number.

This is what I have currently.

```
   int firstnode = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.charAt(0)));
    ListNode root = new ListNode(firstnode);

    for(int i = 1; i<m.length(); ++i) {

    while (root.next ==  null) {

       root.next = new ListNode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.charAt(i))));

    }
    root = root.next;

    }
```

So I am trying to make it so that

```
root(2)->node(1)->node(3)->node(2)->node(1)->node(4)->ListEND
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Variable m is the sum of two linkedlists, so I essentially iterate through the list appending each number to a string and adding them with the numbers in the second string.

       



 String m = String.valueOf(sumOfTwoLists(s,f));
        StringBuilder max = new StringBuilder(m);
        m = max.reverse().toString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I checked, your code is working fine. just that you lost the root node(head) when you change the root variable for inserting a new `ListNode`. Use a temp varaiable for that. Following is the altered code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String m = "213214";
    int firstnode = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.charAt(0)));
    ListNode root = new ListNode(firstnode);


    ListNode temp = root;
    for (int i = 1; i < m.length(); ++i) {

        while (temp.next == null) {
            temp.next = new ListNode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.charAt(i))));
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    temp = root;

    while (temp != null) {
        System.out.print("->" + temp.val);
        temp=temp.next;
    }
}
```

Also you don't need a while loop inside the for loop. It always runs just once.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you. Since root is assigned to new root element, you cannot print. Keep the root element reference and use it for print logic

```
ListNode root = new ListNode(firstnode);
        ListNode printRoot = root;

    for (int i = 1; i < m.length(); i++) {

        if (root.next == null) {

            root.next = new ListNode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.charAt(i))));
            root = root.next;
        }
    }

    while(printRoot !=null) {
        System.out.println(printRoot.val);
        printRoot = printRoot.next;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm does not work. I get a error when I attempt to do

        System.out.println(root.next.val);

Nullpointer exception, also my roots value changes from 2 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 public class SingleLinkedList {

        LinkedList root = null;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SingleLinkedList sll = new SingleLinkedList();
            sll.root = new LinkedList(1);
            sll.root.next = new LinkedList(2);
            sll.root.next.next = new LinkedList(3);
            sll.root.next.next.next = new LinkedList(4);
            sll.root.next.next.next.next = new LinkedList(5);

            while (sll.root != null){
                System.out.println("sll.root.value = " + sll.root.value);
                sll.root = sll.root.next;
            }
        }
    }

    class LinkedList{
        int value;
        LinkedList next;

        LinkedList(int data){
            value = data;
            next = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a root node. Following codes works.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ListNode {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final ListNode root = new ListNode(0);
        "213214".chars()
            .map(Character::getNumericValue)
            .mapToObj(ListNode::new)
            .reduce(root, (n1, n2) -> {
                    n1.next = n2;
                    return n2;
                });
        ;
        System.out.println(root);
    }

    ListNode(final int value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "{"
            + "value=" + value
            + ",next=" + next
            + "}";
    }

    private int value;

    private ListNode next;
}
```